# React: Add Button to Component which Navigates to another page

Tags: react-router

I want to add Button to the Component which after click will navigate to another page.

Currently I am using react 18.0.

Bellow is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import EmployeeService from '../Services/EmployeeService';
import { AddEmployee } from '../Functions/AddEmployee';



class ListEmployeeComponent extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
       
        this.state={
            employees: []
        }

        
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        EmployeeService.getEmployees().then((res) => {
            this.setState({employees:res.data});
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 className='text-center'>Employee List</h2>
                <div className='row'>
                    <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={AddEmployee.bind(this)}>Add Employee</button>
                </div>
                <div className='row'>
                    <table className='table table-striped table-bordered'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Employee First Name</th>
                                <th>Employee Last Name</th>
                                <th>Employee Email Name</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                this.state.employees.map(
                                    employee =>
                                    <tr key={employee.id}>
                                        <td>{employee.firstName}</td>
                                        <td>{employee.lastName}</td>
                                        <td>{employee.email}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ListEmployeeComponent;
```

this is the button:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

export function AddEmployee(a, b) {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    return (
      navigate('http://localhost:3000/add-employee')
    );
  }
```

And on the attached picture is an error which I am getting when I press button:
[Erorr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDDes.png)

Comment: `AddEmployee` is neither a React hook nor a React function component, so it can not use the `useNavigate` hook. The `navigate` function can also only navigate to internal pages within the app; it can't navigate to `"http://localhost:3000/add-employee"`. What really are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: I am trying to navigate withing the app. I tried /add-employee and as well full web url

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, React hooks need to be used from within a function component. The hook in question here is `useNavigate`, which you're calling from a regular function, hence the error. If you instead *inject* the `navigate` variable into the `AddEmployee` function, you shouldn't have a problem.

```js
export function AddEmployee(navigate, a, b) {
    navigate(...);
}

// then within the component, do something akin to
const navigate = useNavigate();
AddEmployee(navigate, a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey after several hours of looking how to solve a problem I have made following

I removed Add Employee function complitely.
I imported Link from react-router-dom and change the Button to be Link to

```
import {React,  Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from  'react-router-dom'
import EmployeeService from '../Services/EmployeeService';

class ListEmployeeComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
       
        this.state={
            employees: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        EmployeeService.getEmployees().then((res) => {
            this.setState({employees:res.data});
        });
    }

    

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 className='text-center'>Employee List</h2>
                <div className='row'>
                    <Link to = '/add-employee' className='btn btn-primary' >Add Employee </Link>
                </div>
                <div className='row'>
                    <table className='table table-striped table-bordered'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Employee First Name</th>
                                <th>Employee Last Name</th>
                                <th>Employee Email Name</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                this.state.employees.map(
                                    employee =>
                                    <tr key={employee.id}>
                                        <td>{employee.firstName}</td>
                                        <td>{employee.lastName}</td>
                                        <td>{employee.email}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ListEmployeeComponent;
```

Comment: Now you're using the correct tools, i.e. components, for the job. The `Link` certainly works here for this purpose.